# parse string with regular expression

Tags: php, regex

I trying to parse this string:

```
$right = '34601)S(1,6)[2] - 34601)(11)[2] + 34601)(3)[2,4]';
```

with following regexp:

```
const word = '(\d{3}\d{2}\)S{0,1}\([^\)]*\)S{0,1}\[[^\]]*\])';
preg_match('/'.word.'{1}(?:\s{1}([+-]{1})\s{1}'.word.'){0,}/', $right, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

i want to return array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 34601)S(1,6)[2] - 34601)(11)[2] + 34601)(3)[2,4]
    [1] => 34601)S(1,6)[2]
    [2] => -
    [3] => 34601)(11)[2]
    [4] => +
    [5] => 34601)(3)[2,4]
)
```

but i return only following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 34601)S(1,6)[2] - 34601)(11)[2] + 34601)(3)[2,4]
    [1] => 34601)S(1,6)[2]
    [2] => +
    [3] => 34601)(3)[2,4]
)
```

I think, its because of [^)]* or [^]]* in the word, 
but how I should correct regexp for matching this in another way?

I tryied to specify it:

```
\d+(?:[,#]\d+){0,}
```

so word become

```
const word = '(\d{3}\d{2}\)S{0,1}\(\d+(?:[,#]\d+){0,}\)S{0,1}\[\d+(?:[,#]\d+){0,}\])';
```

but it gives nothing

Comment: well, i use this, and it works

    preg_match_all('/(?:\s{1}([+-]{1})\s{1}){0,}'.word.'/', $right, $matches);

Comment: so it works with this

    preg_match_all('/(?:\s{1}([+-]{1})\s{1}){0,}'.word.'/', $right, $matches);

and another question, can i match all occurrences of word after the first word with preg_match, or i must use preg_match_all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, i use this, and it works

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\s{1}([+-]{1})\s{1}){0,}'.word.'/', $right, $matches);
```